# How to set admin login page as home page

Tags: wp-admin

How can I set the backend admin login page as the homepage of my wordpress application?

When the user types in art.com, I really want to let me go to art.con/wp-admin.

Is this done on worse press or the server configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin will do exactly that: [Members Only](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members-only/). Don't worry about the warning at the top about not being updated in over 2 years, I use the plugin all the time, there are no issues with it and no security flaws that I have run into. After you install the plugin, there is a small configuration panel under Settings.